# ogr2ogr won't read directory of GeoJSON into GPKG

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, command-line

I have a directory of GeoJSON files, which I want to load as layers into a single new GeoPackage file. According to the [GDAL GeoPackage documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage.html), I can name my destination GeoPackage file, enter a directory of shapefiles as the source, and it will load them each as their own layer/table. Indeed, I've tested this with shapefiles, and it works.

When I try the same thing with GeoJSON files, however, I get this:

```
Unable to open datasource ./seattle_washington_osm with the following drivers.
   …
-> GeoJSON
   …
```

Is this simply not possible with GeoJSON files, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "directory as dataset" is a specific feature of the shapefile driver. From http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html :

> Normally the OGR Shapefile driver treats a whole directory of
>   shapefiles as a dataset, and a single shapefile within that directory
>   as a layer. In this case the directory name should be used as the
>   dataset name. However, it is also possible to use one of the files
>   (.shp, .shx or .dbf) in a shapefile set as the dataset name, and then
>   it will be treated as a dataset with one layer.

Alternative approaches would be to load each file using a loop, or to convert to shapefiles first.

Answer (score 2):

I failed to convert a directory of GeoJSONs into one pgkg using ogr2ogr (GDAL 2.2.3) by using the command `ogr2ogr -f GPKG filename.gpkg ./path/to/geojsons/*`;
But I succeed in using the *-append* parameter in ogr2ogr command to convert GeoJSON data into one pgkg one by one.

I will show my shell scripts here:

```
#! /bin/bash
function read_dir(){
for file in `ls $1` 
do
 res="${file:${#file}-7:7}"
 if [ "$res" == "geojson" ] ;then
  name="${file:0:${#file}-8}" 
  echo $name
  ogr2ogr -f GPKG filename.gpkg  -append $file
 fi
done
}
read_dir $1
```

At last I got the output file called filename.gpkg and it works well.